# Search by textfield input

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Currently i have a query that searched on 'availability' using the following code;

```
    $status = 'available';
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM orders WHERE idorder = "' . $status . '"');
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

My question is; How can i change the variable from $status from 'available' to whatever is entered into the search box?

Comment: Use an html form to pass a data to the query?

Comment: if you are going to use PDO, then be smart enough to use a prepared statement and parameter for `$status`, instead of directly inserting the value and opening yourself up to sql injection - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Where is your search box code? is it an `<input>` inside a `<form>`? Are you using `method="GET"` or `method="POST"`?

Answer (score 1):

This is your search page:

myhtml.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["btnsubmit"]) && !empty($_POST["btnsubmit"]))
{
  $status = $_POST["status"];
  $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM orders WHERE idorder = "' . $status . '"');
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll();

}

?>

<form action="myhtml.php" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="status">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="btnsubmit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Index.html

```
<form action="file.php" method="get">
 <input type="text" name="status">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

File.php

```
<?php
    $status=$_GET['status'];
    $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM orders WHERE idorder = "' . $status . '"');
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
```

Comment: That would be the file your form directs to. MySQL is a server-side language which means you'll have to send the 'status' input back to the server before performing the query.